# How to retrieve interesting fields from a complex list in order to insert them into an sqlite3 table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a list of lists of which each individual list contains the values from one line of a report in a log file.
Values of a data set are spanning n lines of the report. These values are to be inserted in an sqlite3 table.
In between those lines there are values from num_datasets other data sets that are also spanning n lines of the report.
Finally the last x lines of the log report are to be inserted in another sqlite3 table.

Example of a report in the log file where n = 3 and x = 3:

```
Line 1:  300, 0, 1, 798, 53928, 283
Line 2:  300, 0, 2, 210, 36160, 207
Line 3:  300, 0, 3, 78, 12620, 217
Line 4:  300, 0, 4, 67, 11364, 228
Line 5:  300, 0, 1, 34304, 0, 0
Line 6:  300, 0, 2, 27808, 0, 0
Line 7:  300, 0, 3, 30108, 0, 0
Line 8:  300, 0, 4, 31180, 0, 0
Line 9:  300, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 50 
Line 10: 300, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 99
Line 11: 300, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 212
Line 12: 300, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 111
Line 13: 2287, 225372, 1324, 173308
Line 14: 0, 0, 0, 0
Line 15: 0, 2404
```

This data will be stored in the following list:

```
sourcelist = [['300', '0', '1', '798', '53928', '283'],
             ['300', '0', '2', '210', '36160', '207'],
             ['300', '0', '3', '78', '12620', '217'],
             ['300', '0', '4', '67', '11364', '228'], 
             ['300', '0', '1', '34304', '0', '0'],
             ['300', '0', '2', '27808', '0', '0'],
             ['300', '0', '3', '30108', '0', '0'],
             ['300', '0', '4', '31180', '0', '0'],
             ['300', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '50'],
             ['300', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '99'],
             ['300', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '212'],
             ['300', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '111'],
             ['2287', '225372', '1324', '173308'],
             ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
             ['0', '2404']]
```

I am looking for an efficient and fast way to combine the appropriate lines so they can be inserted into one sqlite3 table.
I came up with the following python code:

```
>>> sourcelist = [['300', '0', '1', '798', '53928', '283'],
...              ['300', '0', '2', '210', '36160', '207'],
...              ['300', '0', '3', '78', '12620', '217'],
...              ['300', '0', '4', '67', '11364', '228'], 
...              ['300', '0', '1', '34304', '0', '0'],
...              ['300', '0', '2', '27808', '0', '0'],
...              ['300', '0', '3', '30108', '0', '0'],
...              ['300', '0', '4', '31180', '0', '0'],
...              ['300', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '50'],
...              ['300', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '99'],
...              ['300', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '212'],
...              ['300', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '111'],
...              ['2287', '225372', '1324', '173308'],
...              ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
...              ['0', '2404']]
>>> n = 3
>>> x = 3
>>> num_datasets = (len(sourcelist) - x) // n
>>> parts = zip(*[iter(sourcelist[:-x])]*num_datasets)        
>>> combine_parts_per_dataset = []             
>>> for i in range(num_datasets):
...     for e in parts:
...         combine_parts_per_dataset.append(e[i])
... 
>>> dataset_list = zip(*[iter(combine_parts_per_dataset)]*n)                                          
>>> dataset_list[0]
(['300', '0', '1', '798', '53928', '283'], ['300', '0', '1', '34304', '0', '0'], ['300', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '50'])
>>> dataset_list[1]
(['300', '0', '2', '210', '36160', '207'], ['300', '0', '2', '27808', '0', '0'], ['300', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '99'])
>>> dataset_list[2]
(['300', '0', '3', '78', '12620', '217'], ['300', '0', '3', '30108', '0', '0'], ['300', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '212'])
>>> dataset_list[3]
(['300', '0', '4', '67', '11364', '228'], ['300', '0', '4', '31180', '0', '0'], ['300', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '111'])
```

Now I am able to retrieve the interesting fields of each dataset so I can insert them into an sqlite3 table:

```
>>> for e in dataset_list:
...     print e[0][0], e[0][2], e[0][4], e[1][3], e[2][6]
... 
300 1 53928 34304 50
300 2 36160 27808 99
300 3 12620 30108 212
300 4 11364 31180 111
>>> print sourcelist[-3][0], sourcelist[-3][1], sourcelist[-2][2], sourcelist[-1][1]
2287 225372 0 2404
```

The following code is doing the same thing:

```
>>> x = 3
>>> n = 3
>>> num_datasets = (len(sourcelist) - x) // n
>>> l = []
>>> for s in range(0, n+1):
...     for i in range(s, len(sourcelist) - x, num_datasets):
...         l.append(sourcelist[i])
... 
>>> dataset_list = zip(*[iter(l)]*n)
>>> for e in dataset_list:
...     print e[0][0], e[0][2], e[0][4], e[1][3], e[2][6]
... 
300 1 53928 34304 50
300 2 36160 27808 99
300 3 12620 30108 212
300 4 11364 31180 111
```

However, I think it could be much simpler and more efficient. Are there any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example i threw together that uses `itemgetter` and `groupby`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> sourcelist = [['300', '0', '1', '798', '53928', '283'],
...              ['300', '0', '2', '210', '36160', '207'],
...              ['300', '0', '3', '78', '12620', '217'],
...              ['300', '0', '4', '67', '11364', '228'], 
...              ['300', '0', '1', '34304', '0', '0'],
...              ['300', '0', '2', '27808', '0', '0'],
...              ['300', '0', '3', '30108', '0', '0'],
...              ['300', '0', '4', '31180', '0', '0'],
...              ['300', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '50'],
...              ['300', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '99'],
...              ['300', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '212'],
...              ['300', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '111'],
...              ['2287', '225372', '1324', '173308'],
...              ['0', '0', '0', '0'],
...              ['0', '2404']]
>>> n = 3
>>> n_list = []
>>> for last in range(n):
...       n_list.append(sourcelist.pop(-1))
... 
>>> print(n_list)
[['0', '2404'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['2287', '225372', '1324', '173308']]
>>> print(sourcelist)
[['300', '0', '1', '798', '53928', '283'], 
 ['300', '0', '2', '210', '36160', '207'], 
 ['300', '0', '3', '78', '12620', '217'], 
 ['300', '0', '4', '67', '11364', '228'], 
 ['300', '0', '1', '34304', '0', '0'], 
 ['300', '0', '2', '27808', '0', '0'], 
 ['300', '0', '3', '30108', '0', '0'], 
 ['300', '0', '4', '31180', '0', '0'], 
 ['300', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '50'], 
 ['300', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '99'], 
 ['300', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '212'], 
 ['300', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '111']]
>>> groupby_column = 2
>>> s = sorted(sourcelist,key=itemgetter(groupby_column))
>>> print(s)
[['300', '0', '1', '798', '53928', '283'], 
 ['300', '0', '1', '34304', '0', '0'], 
 ['300', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '50'], 
 ['300', '0', '2', '210', '36160', '207'], 
 ['300', '0', '2', '27808', '0', '0'], 
 ['300', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '99'], 
 ['300', '0', '3', '78', '12620', '217'], 
 ['300', '0', '3', '30108', '0', '0'], 
 ['300', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '212'], 
 ['300', '0', '4', '67', '11364', '228'], 
 ['300', '0', '4', '31180', '0', '0'], 
 ['300', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '111']]
>>> for key, group in groupby(s, lambda x: x[groupby_column]):
...       print(key,list(group))
... 
('1', [['300', '0', '1', '798', '53928', '283'], ['300', '0', '1', '34304', '0', '0'], ['300', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '50']])
('2', [['300', '0', '2', '210', '36160', '207'], ['300', '0', '2', '27808', '0', '0'], ['300', '0', '2', '0', '0', '0', '99']])
('3', [['300', '0', '3', '78', '12620', '217'], ['300', '0', '3', '30108', '0', '0'], ['300', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '212']])
('4', [['300', '0', '4', '67', '11364', '228'], ['300', '0', '4', '31180', '0', '0'], ['300', '0', '4', '0', '0', '0', '111']])
```

And then your could do another sortby and/or groupby on another column/s based on data of interest.